# What does this JavaScript snippet mean?

Tags: javascript, function, grammar

I have not met this type of grammar before. What does it mean? To what technique is it related?

```
(function(fun) { 

})(myFunkyAlert);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an anonymous function that will run as soon as it is declared. Its parameter is `myFunkyAlert` and inside the function it will be referenced as the `fun` variable.

The reason we usually write a function like that is to avoid conflicts, due to scoping.

Example:

```
var myFunkyAlert = "The funky alert";

(function(fun) { 
   alert(fun);
})(myFunkyAlert);
```

This will result in an alert with the message "The funky alert".

Answer (score 2):

You're defining an anonymous function and then calling it with `myFunkyAlert` as an argument.

Comment: It might be helpful to give examples to when this idiom would be useful.