# (function(){})() Is there any documentation of this?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does an anonymous function in JavaScript work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140089/how-does-an-anonymous-function-in-javascript-work)
>   [What does this JavaScript snippet mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771406/what-does-this-javascript-snippet-mean)

I use in my scripts:

```
(function(){
...[code]..
})()
```

I can't find documentation about this, i have see scripts when this form take args.

```
(function(){
...[code]..
})(arg1,arg2)
```

Somebody have a link or a good explanation about this javascript function?

Comment: That would be called a function - specifically, "Immediately Invoked Function Expression"

Comment: there's plenty about this one the web, but this one is pretty clear: http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

Answer (score 1):

this is just regular javascript.

you instanciate an anonymous function, and then call it with 2 arguments.

The confusing part I think is the on-the-fly aspect of the operation.

You could have done (at higher cost):

```
var hnd = function() {...};
hnd(arg1,arg2);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's known as a Self-Executing Anonymous Function.

[Here](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) is the first Google result, which gives a solid overview.